# Directional Derivative of a function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been trying to do the following question without much success, what seems to be a trivial one, has showed how bad my understanding about multivariable calculus is.

Given $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,2)=-1$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1,2)=3$

There is a unit vector u=ai+bj such as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(1,2)=4$

According to what I know, I simply had to use the directional derivative formula, which is the partial derivative of a function with respect to a unit vector:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(1,2)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,2)a+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1,2)b$$

which led to a true(T) statement, but it is false(F).

I really would like to understand what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what you know about the partials of $f$, your equation gives
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = -a+3b = 4.
$$
(I am dropping all references to $(1,2)$ out of laziness.)

Solve for $a$ to get $a = 3b-4$.  But wait, as $u = \langle a, b \rangle$ is to be a unit vector you also know that $a^2+b^2=1$.  Plug in $a=3b-4$ and do all the algebra.   What do you see?

When you do this right, you might be surprised by what you get.  It is a great exercise in understanding directional derivatives and gradients to see why you shouldn't be surprised.  At this point you really understand it.

Comment: Wow, the delta in this case is negative, considering that a and b belong to the real space, it is really false, but I still don't get it intuitively.

Comment: I forgot to thank you, thx for the reply. Do you recommend any books on the subject?

Comment: Try this.  Do the same problem but ask for the directional derivative to be $1$ instead of $4$.  Most of this stuff is helpfully phrased in terms of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \nabla f \cdot u$, and then playing around with the cosine interpretation of the dot product.

Comment: Any decent multivariable calculus book should do the trick.  They all give about the same treatment.